# Visual Basic Got 424 Object Required Error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I've tried to run this code, but I have received 424 error, I'm new to Visual Basic and I don't know how to fix this bug :(  Thanks so much

```
Dim a, b As Integer

    'compute weekly change BAS
    For a = 1 To 8
     For b = 1 To 9
      
      If Range("AA4").Cells(a, b) <> 0 Then
       Changed.Cells(a, b) = (Range("AB4").Cells(a, b) - Range("AA4").Cells(a, b)) / Range("AA4").Cells(a, b)
      
      Else
       Changed.Cells(a, b) = "n/a"
      End If
    
     Next b
    Next a
```

Comment: Is Changed the name of the worksheet?

Comment: What line shows the error?  I don't see where `Changed` is ever declared. By the way Visual Basic (VB) is NOT the same as Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)

Answer (score 0):

If `Changed` is a Worksheet Object, you need to `Dim` it and `Set` it.